# USB PTP camera no longer working after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, camera

I have a Fujifilm F100fd camera, and it used to work fine with Ubuntu 17.04: after connecting it, import in Shotwell showed the photos and I could copy them to the computer. After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, Shotwell still shows the camera, but trying to import from it results in an error message `Unable to fetch previews from the camera: Unspecified error (-1)`.

It shows in `lsusb` as

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04cb:01e0 Fuji Photo Film Co., Ltd
```

But `dmesg` shows

```
[ 1320.087128] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1324.122507] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1324.241439] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04cb, idProduct=01e0
[ 1324.241444] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1324.241447] usb 1-2: Product: USB PTP Camera
[ 1324.241449] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 592D31373032081124B4433011D6D2
[ 1831.260528] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1831.260533] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 1831.260535] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1831.260538] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
```

I also tried mounting with `gphotofs`:

```
mkdir ~/camera
gphotofs ~/camera/
ls ~/camera
```

But it gives `Protocol error`.

I checked and `libgphoto2` is installed. What else could be the problem, or how could I find out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/1731341 may be the culprit. It is fixed upstream.